# Prevent SPACE and ARROW from scrolling [Game Iframe]

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, keydown, preventdefault

I have a problem with preventing Space and Arrows to scroll down/up when the game is focused on an online gaming site for kids.

To prevent this functionality on a web page, I know, we can use:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if(["Space","ArrowUp","ArrowDown","ArrowLeft","ArrowRight"].indexOf(e.code) > -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
```

**But, the problem is when the game is focused.**

The games are mirrored through `iframe` and once the user will click on the game and the game iframe will focus, the `code` from above will just not work anymore.

Of course, it's frustrating because we have games where you need to use the Space or Up/Down Arrows to move, jump, or something else - but whenever you will press those buttons, the page will start scrolling.

Page example:

```
...
<body>
<iframe src="https://example.com/game/game21/index.html" width="X" height="Y"></iframe>
...
```

I don't have the right to modify the src page.

Comment: Did you try setting the body overflow to none with css in `/game/game21/index.html`? `body { overflow:none;width:100vh;height:100vh}`

Comment: @Daantje, I tried but that didn't help. If it helps, here is an example - please take in mind that the problem is active in Firefox, not in Chrome. [link](https://www.play-games.com/game/26780/counterfeit-cat-nine-lives.html)

Comment: So add the code in the iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `e.stopPropagation();`. Try this:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(["Space","ArrowUp","ArrowDown","ArrowLeft","ArrowRight"].indexOf(e.code) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: Corrected my comment after testing ;)

Comment: It seems that with your latest solution, it is working! Thank you! :)